# Не заносить в базу mysql, если не все поля заполнены

Tags: mysql

При вставке в базу mysql

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pages (title, opisanie, pageid) VALUES('test', '', '12')");
```

Нужно, чтобы вставка в базу не происходила, если есть пустые значения, как в примере. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Создать триггер, пример по ссылке

проверить содержимое и если данные невалидные, поднять исключение

А лучше проверять на клиенте.

https://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER example_before_insert_allow_only_one_active
     BEFORE INSERT ON example_tbl FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
          IF NEW.active = 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM example_tbl 
               WHERE active=1 AND foreign_key_id=NEW.foreign_key_id) > 0
          THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only one active row allowed per type';
          END IF;
     END;
$$
```